# PHP Regex to remove everything after a character

Tags: php, regex

So I've seen a couple articles that go a little too deep, so I'm not sure what to remove from the regex statements they make.

I've basically got this

**foo:bar** all the way to **anotherfoo:bar;seg98y34g.?sdebvw h segvu** (anything goes really)

I need a PHP regex to remove EVERYTHING after the colon. the first part can be any length (but it never contains a colon. so in both cases above I'd end up with

**foo** and **anotherfoo**

after doing something like this horrendous example of psuedo-code

```
$string = 'foo:bar';
$newstring = regex_to_remove_everything_after_":"($string);
```

**EDIT**

after posting this, would an `explode()` work reliably enough? Something like

```
$pieces = explode(':', 'foo:bar') 
$newstring = $pieces[0];
```

Comment: well this is done more easily with strpos and and substrings.... why use a hammer to hit a fly???

Comment: anyways, I am waiting for a solution too, so a +1

Comment: Just use explode if you can reliably say that the colon is the delimiter.

Comment: I thought regex might be the only way, until (of course) after posting, I thought maybe exploding would work? I considered deleting it and testing the explode, but I'll keep it up to a) help those who stumble on it and b) so I can see if there's a deemed "better" solution :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) would do what you're asking for, but you can make it one step by using [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php).

```
$beforeColon = current(explode(':', $string));
```

I would not use a regex here (that involves some work behind the scenes for a relatively simple action), nor would I use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) with [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) (as that would, effectively, be traversing the string twice). Most importantly, this provides the person who reads the code with an immediate, "Ah, yes, that is what the author is trying to do!" instead of, "Wait, what is happening again?"

The only exception to that is if you happen to know that the string is excessively long: I would not `explode` a 1 Gb file. Instead:

```
$beforeColon = substr($string, 0, strpos($string,':'));
```

I also feel `substr` isn't quite as easy to read: in `current(explode` you can see the delimiter immediately with no extra function calls and there is only one incident of the variable (which makes it less prone to human errors). Basically I read `current(explode` as "I am taking the first incident of anything prior to this string" as opposed to `substr`, which is "I am getting a substring starting at the 0 position and continuing until this string."

Comment: +1 for showing me `current()` - would simplify alot of other functions I've got that use my above methodology. And for explaining why I shouldn't use Regex /strpos for something this effetively simple, thanks!

Comment: current() is just magic. Where do people learn all this stuff.

Answer (score 9):

Your `explode` solution does the trick. If you really want to use regexes for some reason, you could simply do this:

```
$newstring = preg_replace("/(.*?):(.*)/", "$1", $string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll save that regex for when I need it though for sure!

Answer (score 3):

A bit more succinct than other examples:

```
current(explode(':', $string));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use RegEx that m.buettner wrote, but his example returns everything BEFORE ':', if you want everything after ':' just use $2 instead of $1:

```
$newstring = preg_replace("/(.*?):(.*)/", "$2", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following. demo: http://codepad.org/bUXKN4el

```
<?php 
  $s = 'anotherfoo:bar;seg98y34g.?sdebvw h segvu';
  $result = array_shift(explode(':', $s));
  echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to use a regex?

```
list($beforeColon) = explode(':', $string);
```

Comment: Maybe if we use the preg_match will be helpful