# remove part of string after a special character

Tags: php, substr, strpos

What I am trying to do is remove a `*` and the number after it from a string.

```
$string = 'something*10';
$string2 = 'something*1';
```

needs to output

```
something
something
```

not

```
something*10
something*1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = current(explode('*', 'something*10'));
```

As found here : [REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696996/php-regex-to-remove-everything-after-a-character)

Running Example : [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/xougrz)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code which is easy

```
echo $string = substr($string, 0, strpos( $string, '*'));
echo $string2 = substr($string2, 0, strpos( $string2, '*'));
```

Let me know if working. It should work. Thnx

Reference: [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) with this regular expression `/\*\d+/` to solve your problem.

*The other answers assume that the * are followed by numbers which is incorrect based on your requirement.*

Comment: for the input `something*10MagicalStringAlso`, the correct output should be `somethingMagicalStringAlso` based on OP's requirement.

Comment: you can't assume that based on his examples. Ill sit on the fence on that one and wait for OP `remove part of string after a special character` would suggest you are incorrect

Comment: Quoted from OP: `remove a * and the number after it`. Not clear enough?

Comment: with your attitude you've missed the question "remove part of string after a special character" so to answer you, no .. its not clear enough

Comment: The devil is in the detail. One should not rely on the headline solely.