# str_replace time from datetime

Tags: php, datetime, str-replace

I use datetime function and there is everything fine with that. Is there possible to cut off time and show only date?

For example I have 2015/01/20 08:00 and there should be: 2015/01/20.

The problem is, that value isn't static. Please do not offer use only date function, I need to solve it with datetime.

Comment: `echo date_format($date, 'Y/m/d');` ? Something like this?

Comment: @Xinel you should show what you've tried.

Comment: @Rizier123 essentially what I think the OP wants is exactly that, but with the OO interface version of that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
$date = new DateTime('2015/01/20 08:00');
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
```

DateTime class has a method format, wchich return the saved date in a given format (php date format, for example 'Y/m/d').

---

If You want string only solution (for example use explode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$string = '2015/01/20 08:00';
$date_parts = explode(' ', $string);
echo $date_parts[0]; // 2015/01/20
echo $date_parts[1]; // 08:00
```

Explode make an array from string, based on a "break" character, in this example space. array[0] is the first string before space, and array[1] is the second one (after space).

---

According to this one: [PHP Regex to remove everything after a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696996/php-regex-to-remove-everything-after-a-character)

Yu can also use:

```
$date = current(explode(' ', '2015/01/20 08:00'));
```

Or

```
$string = '2015/01/20 08:00';
$date = substr($string, 0, strpos($string,' '));
```

I hope there is no need of describing the solution, as everyting needed is in the link.

Comment: You welcome. I hope the answer is complete and clear :).