# How to use substr and strrpos in order to clean a string after specific chars?

Tags: php

I want to to remove from the following string, anything after the keywords I have set. Have in mind that the url variable is just an example, and in real life it can take a lot of forms.

For example, the following,

```
$url = '/resutls?offer=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw1f_pBRAEEiwApp0JK';
```

I want it to be

`/resutls?offer=1`

but when I am using the following code

```
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&gclid'));
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&utm_source'));
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '?utm_campaign'));
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '?utm_medium'));
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '?token'));
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&fbclid'));
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&utm_campaign'));
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&utm_medium'));
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&token'));

echo $url;
```

the url variable returns empty.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why aren't you using regex?

Comment: @Mido I do not have the education to do so, can you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Regex to remove everything after a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696996/php-regex-to-remove-everything-after-a-character)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava please have in mind that I want this to be for multiple

Comment: First of all, why strrpos and not strpos? Also, your current solution [seems to work](https://3v4l.org/FrNpt) for me.

Comment: @vivek_23 it works because you used only the first line. He repeatedly overwritten `$url` this is why it's eventually empty https://3v4l.org/lMCIc

Comment: @Mido Ok got it.

Comment: @EnexoOnoma Note that the function [strrpos](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) returns `false` if a match isn't present. You didn't handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` to get any of the keywords you want.

```
$parsed = parse_url('/resutls?offer=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw1f_pBRAEEiwApp0JK');
parse_str($parsed['query'], $output);

echo($output['offer']);  // should print 1
```

You could use this to reconstruct your URL as well:

```
echo $parsed['path'] . '?offer=' . $output['offer']; // prints /resutls?offer=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly overwriting the variable `$url`, check [what happens](https://3v4l.org/Kbm84) after the first echo.

I would suggest you either use regex to extract the page name and 'offer' parameter and exclude the other parameters or use something like [`parse_url`](https://3v4l.org/BCPck).

I created [this](https://3v4l.org/BCPck) quickly for you, it extracts the path as well as the params using `parse_str` and `parse_url`

Answer (score 0):

I've wrapped the 'delete after if found' into a function.  This first checks if the string is present, then if it is it will do the `substr()` part...

```
function trimIfSet ( string $base, string $pattern )   {
    if (( $pos = strrpos($base, $pattern)) !== false ){
        $base = substr($base, 0, $pos);
    }
    return $base;
}

$url = '/resutls?offer=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw1f_pBRAEEiwApp0JK';
$url = trimIfSet( $url, '&gclid');
$url = trimIfSet( $url, '&utm_source');

echo $url;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The fact that it deletes only if it is found, is some kind of optimization ?

Comment: Which would be the fastest way? First check and then delete, or try to delete no matter what ?

Comment: The problem is that if the pattern isn't found, `strrpos()` returns false, so I think it's easier to just not do the delete.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted to do in your code was:

```
$url = '/resutls?offer=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw1f_pBRAEEiwApp0JK';

$url = explode('&gclid', $url)[0];
$url = explode('&utm_source', $url)[0];
$url = explode('?utm_campaign', $url)[0];
$url = explode('?utm_medium', $url)[0];
$url = explode('?token', $url)[0];
$url = explode('&fbclid', $url)[0];
$url = explode('&utm_campaign', $url)[0];
$url = explode('&utm_medium', $url)[0];
$url = explode('&token', $url)[0];

echo $url;
```

But of course you could save some lines of code using regex instead...

Comment: Thank you for this. What would be a regex solution for this ?

Comment: it depends on your needs, is the parameter "offer=x" always the one you want to keep ?

Comment: No, this is just an example, the url can be anything

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$url = '/resutls?offer=1&gclid=1&utm_source=21213';

$url = strrpos( $url, '&gclid')?substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&gclid')):$url; 
$url = strrpos( $url, '&utm_source')?substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&utm_source')):$url; 
$url = strrpos( $url, '?utm_campaign')?substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '?utm_campaign')):$url;
$url = strrpos( $url, '?utm_medium')?substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '?utm_medium')):$url;
$url = strrpos( $url, '?token')?substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '?token')):$url;
$url = strrpos( $url, '&fbclid')?substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&fbclid')):$url;
$url = strrpos( $url, '&utm_campaign')?substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&utm_campaign')):$url;
$url = strrpos( $url, '&utm_medium')?substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&utm_medium')):$url;
$url = strrpos( $url, '&token')?substr($url, 0, strrpos( $url, '&token')):$url;

echo $url;
?>
```